# Text does not show string in CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, text, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer Class to set a countdown which will start will when the user clicks some Button.
This is the code that includes the CountDownTimer

```
 public class play extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

        private TapCountDownTimer countDownTimer;   
        private final long startTime = 10;
        private final long interval = 1;
        private TextView countdowntext;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.play);

        countDownTimer = new TapCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        countdowntext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdowntext);
        countdowntext.setText(String.valueOf(startTime));

            Button buttonstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
                   buttonstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v){
                      countDownTimer.start();
                      }                
                });

            Button buttonstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
                   buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v){
                      countDownTimer.cancel();
                      }                
                });

    public class TapCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public TapCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
            {
                super(startTime, interval);
            }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
            countdowntext.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1));

            }
        @Override
        public void onFinish()
            {
            countdowntext.setText("Time's up!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I set the text in this line

```
countdowntext.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1));
```

But it's not working and the text shows "Time's Up" instead of the countdown.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe that is because `interval` is set to `1`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein okay i will change that

Answer (score 0):

Your `startTime` and `interval` are erroneosly set in **seconds**.
Just multiply both by 1000, since you need **milliseconds**.

Also note that you don't need **long**s, for holding such low values.
Integers will do.

```
    private final int startTime = 10000; // 10 secs
    private final int interval = 1000;   // 1s  = 1000 ms
```

Also this has no meaning: `millisUntilFinished/1` (dividing any number by 1 gives you the original number).
It must be `millisUntilFinished / 1000`